# Correct way to include two Variables inside brackets?

Tags: php

I need to include two variables inside the brackets below, whats the correct way to do this please?

```
//Needs two variables stated
listDebug();
```

Comment: Please accept the answer below which actually did it for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8467982/367456 - I also removed your update from the question because it's not helpful that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this to work instead I did listDebug($var1.$var2); Thanks for your replies and advice.

Answer (score 4):

The proper syntax for passing 2 variables to a function in PHP looks like this:

```
//Needs two variables stated
listDebug($var1, $var2);
```

### Edit:

Judging by the comments, it looks like `listDebug()` is a library function that only accepts one argument and that you cannot edit. It logs information to a database and its single argument represents the string to be logged. In this case, you want to log the value of 2 separate values. The most straight forward approach would be simply concatenate them together like so:

```
listDebug($var1 . ' ' . $var2);
```

Comment: Hehe, it was easy )) And will work only if `listDebug` accepts 2 arguments

Comment: This didn't work for me, only the first variable came through.. To get this to work instead I did listDebug($var1.$var2);
Which works! Thanks for your reply anyway :)

Comment: @zerkms: Actually, it will work even if `listDebug` accepts less than 2 args. See [`func_get_args`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php).

Comment: @A Smith: This answer most definitely works. I guarantee it. You're doing something weird. The dot operator is for concatenation. You're combining both variables into a single argument and passing that. Make sure your function accepts 2 _separate_ args and use the comma, not the dot.

Comment: @Asaph: what I wanted to say is that it will work only if `listDebug` authors knew about `func_get_args` and implemented the functions keeping in mind `func_get_args` and possibility of passing several arguments at once. And probably they don't, as long as OP says it didn't work ;-)

Comment: @zermks: That makes sense. I was being pedantic anyway. `func_get_args()` shouldn't be used in this context. It would just be confusing.

Comment: Yes it looks like it doesn't support two variables, as I'm not the author of this particular code, I must work around it for the time being, so to keep them seperated visually, can use listDebug($var1." ".$var2);

Comment: @A Smith: What does `listDebug()` do? Does it just log or echo a string variable?

Comment: @Asaph it creates a log in the db.

Comment: @A Smith: Ok, then stick with the concatenation. I think we were all a little thrown off by the wording of your question. You don't want to actually pass 2 arguments, as you were asking. What you should have asked was "How can I combine the values of 2 variables into a single variable so that I can pass the information into a function which only accepts 1 argument." or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
listDebug($variable1,$variable2);
```

Will need more information if you are looking for more.

Comment: This didn't work for me, only the first variable came through.. To get this to work instead I did listDebug($var1.$var2);
Which works! Thanks for your reply anyway :)

Comment: the dot is a concatenation in PHP. You are combining $var1 and $var2. listDebug() does not accept two parameters. Check the function. It should be something like: `function listDebug($var1,$var2) {...}`

Comment: Hi, thanks for explaining, I cannot edit the actual code as its part of an app that I havn't wrote...

Comment: @ASmith Understood. Please be aware that using $var1.$var2 will combine the variables, giving you unwanted results most likely. If you are looking to combine them and pass them to the function, then this is correct. Otherwise, you might want to consider passing them separately or using a different function.

Comment: it will show up in a log, and not be used any further then this, so should be okay?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like `listDebug` function implementation hasn't been written to accept more than one argument.

So you just cannot pass 2 arguments there. Call the function twice... or rewrite the function to respect second argument.